# Could not send data from Server to client via websocket

Tags: c#, .net, html, websocket

I guess I need a hand here. What I understand is once I send data to my client, the `onmessage()` will be fired.

I have created my websocket server in  C# and my client in HTML5. I can successfully establish websocket connection but I can't send data to my client. Or perhaps, I am already sending but is not reading. Well, it just doesn't fires up my `onmessage()`. Please help.

C# (.net 4.0 version):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;




namespace WebSocketServer
{
    public enum ServerLogLevel { Nothing, Subtle, Verbose };
    public delegate void ClientConnectedEventHandler(WebSocketConnection sender, EventArgs e);

    public class WebSocketServer
    {
        #region private members
        private string webSocketOrigin;     // location for the protocol handshake
        private string webSocketLocation;   // location for the protocol handshake
        #endregion
        static private string guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
        static IPEndPoint ipLocal;

        public event ClientConnectedEventHandler ClientConnected;

        /// <summary>
        /// TextWriter used for logging
        /// </summary>
        public TextWriter Logger { get; set; }     // stream used for logging

        /// <summary>
        /// How much information do you want, the server to post to the stream
        /// </summary>
        public ServerLogLevel LogLevel = ServerLogLevel.Subtle;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the connections of the server
        /// </summary>
        public List<WebSocketConnection> Connections { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the listener socket. This socket is used to listen for new client connections
        /// </summary>
        public Socket ListenerSocker { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the port of the server
        /// </summary>
        public int Port { get; private set; }


        public WebSocketServer(int port, string origin, string location)
        {
            Port = port;
            Connections = new List<WebSocketConnection>();
            webSocketOrigin = origin;
            webSocketLocation = location;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the server - making it listen for connections
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            // create the main server socket, bind it to the local ip address and start listening for clients
            ListenerSocker = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Port);
            ListenerSocker.Bind(ipLocal);
            ListenerSocker.Listen(100);



            LogLine(DateTime.Now + "> server stated on " + ListenerSocker.LocalEndPoint, ServerLogLevel.Subtle);

            ListenForClients();
        }

        // look for connecting clients
        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            ListenerSocker.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
        }

        private void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            string headerResponse = "";

            // create a new socket for the connection
            var clientSocket = ListenerSocker.EndAccept(asyn);
            var i = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
            headerResponse = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0, i);
            //Console.WriteLine(headerResponse);


            if (clientSocket != null)
            {

                // Console.WriteLine("HEADER RESPONSE:"+headerResponse);
                var key = headerResponse.Replace("ey:", "`")
                              .Split('`')[1]                     // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ== \r\n .......
                              .Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0]  // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
                              .Trim();
                var test1 = AcceptKey(ref key);
                var newLine = "\r\n";
                var name = "Charmaine";
                var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                         + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                         + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine
                         + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + test1 + newLine + newLine
                         + "Testing lang naman po:" + name
                         ;

                // which one should I use? none of them fires the onopen method
                clientSocket.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
            }





            // keep track of the new guy
            var clientConnection = new WebSocketConnection(clientSocket);
            Connections.Add(clientConnection);
            // clientConnection.Disconnected += new WebSocketDisconnectedEventHandler(ClientDisconnected);
            Console.WriteLine("New user: " + ipLocal);
            // invoke the connection event
            if (ClientConnected != null)
                ClientConnected(clientConnection, EventArgs.Empty);

            if (LogLevel != ServerLogLevel.Nothing)
                clientConnection.DataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedFromClient);



            // listen for more clients
            ListenForClients();

        }

        void ClientDisconnected(WebSocketConnection sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connections.Remove(sender);
            LogLine(DateTime.Now + "> " + sender.ConnectionSocket.LocalEndPoint + " disconnected", ServerLogLevel.Subtle);
        }

        void DataReceivedFromClient(WebSocketConnection sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Log(DateTime.Now + "> data from " + sender.ConnectionSocket.LocalEndPoint, ServerLogLevel.Subtle);
            Log(": " + e.Data + "\n" + e.Size + " bytes", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("", ServerLogLevel.Subtle);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// send a string to all the clients (you spammer!)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">the string to send</param>
        public void SendToAll(string data)
        {
            Connections.ForEach(a => a.Send(data));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// send a string to all the clients except one
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">the string to send</param>
        /// <param name="indifferent">the client that doesn't care</param>
        public void SendToAllExceptOne(string data, WebSocketConnection indifferent)
        {
            foreach (var client in Connections)
            {
                if (client != indifferent)
                    client.Send(data);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes care of the initial handshaking between the the client and the server
        /// </summary>


        private void Log(string str, ServerLogLevel level)
        {
            if (Logger != null && (int)LogLevel >= (int)level)
            {
                Logger.Write(str);
            }
        }

        private void LogLine(string str, ServerLogLevel level)
        {
            Log(str + "\r\n", level);
        }

        private static string AcceptKey(ref string key)
        {
            string longKey = key + guid;
            byte[] hashBytes = ComputeHash(longKey);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }
        static SHA1 sha1 = SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
        private static byte[] ComputeHash(string str)
        {
            return sha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
        }



        private void ShakeHands(Socket conn)
        {
            using (var stream = new NetworkStream(conn))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                //read handshake from client (no need to actually read it, we know its there):
                LogLine("Reading client handshake:", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
                string r = null;
                while (r != "")
                {
                    r = reader.ReadLine();
                    LogLine(r, ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
                }

                // send handshake to the client
                writer.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake");
                writer.WriteLine("Upgrade: WebSocket");
                writer.WriteLine("Connection: Upgrade");
                writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Origin: " + webSocketOrigin);
                writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Location: " + webSocketLocation);
                writer.WriteLine("");
            }


            // tell the nerds whats going on
            LogLine("Sending handshake:", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("Upgrade: WebSocket", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("Connection: Upgrade", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("WebSocket-Origin: " + webSocketOrigin, ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("WebSocket-Location: " + webSocketLocation, ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);

            LogLine("Started listening to client", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            //conn.Listen();
        }


    }
}
```

HTML5:

```
<!HTML>
    <head>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");  
            socket.onopen = function(evt){  
                alert("Socket has been opened!");  

            }  
            socket.onmessage = function(evt) {      
                alert("On message fired up!");
            };
        });
        </script>  
    </head>
</HTML>
```

And this is what I got in my response headers:

[image: Request-Response Headers]

And this is my Send method:

```
public void Send(string str)
        {
            if (ConnectionSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {

                    // start with a 0x00
                    ConnectionSocket.Send(new byte[] { (byte)WrapperBytes.Start }, 1, 0);
                    // send the string
                    ConnectionSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
                    /*
                    writer.Write(str);
                    writer.Flush();*/

                    // end with a 0xFF
                    ConnectionSocket.Send(new byte[] { (byte)WrapperBytes.End }, 1, 0);
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (Disconnected != null)

                        Disconnected(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Websocket messages are not sent as plain text.  Each message must be framed as described in the [data framing section](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.2) of RFC6455.  Does your `WebSocketConnection` class' `Send` method apply this framing?

Comment: hi.. I updated my question. I provided the code for my send method

Comment: Thanks, looks like my first comment was on the right lines.  I've posted an answer with a bit more detail.

Comment: does .net framework 4.0 supports this data framing?

Comment: (Replacing earlier wrong comment) No, .net 4.0 doesn't have any support for websockets.  You need to move to .net 4.5 for that.  See MSDN docs for the [System.Net.WebSockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.aspx) namespace for details.

Answer (score 3):

The websocket protocol went through some incompatible changes between early drafts.  It looks like your code is split between supporting recent and earlier versions.  Handshaking appears based on [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) (or its earlier Hybi drafts); message sending appears to be based on the earlier, incompatible [Hixie-76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) variant.

It is possible to support multiple protocol variants in your server.  Almost all browsers (Safari for Windows being a possible exception) support the more recent variant now though so I presume this is the one you'll want to prioritise.

To support the latest protocol variant, you'll need to change `WebSocketConnection.Send` to implement framing as described in the [data framing section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2) of RFC6455.

Code for receiving messages in `WebSocketConnection` will likely need similar changes.